# Best method for PostgreSQL incremental backup

Tags: postgresql, backup

I am currently using `pg_dump` piped to `gzip` piped to `split`. But the problem with this is that all output files are always changed. So checksum-based backup always copies all data.

Are there any other good ways to perform an incremental backup of a PostgreSQL database, where a full database can be restored from the backup data?

For instance, if `pg_dump` could make everything absolutely ordered, so all changes are applied only at the end of the dump, or similar.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I also have the same requirement i.e incremental back up in PostgreSQL. I have gone through many articles and websites but i could not found a clear cut way to do incremental backup in PostgreSQL. Do PostgreSQL support incremental backup independently without third party tools like pg rman? Please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Update:** [Check out Barman](http://www.pgbarman.org/) for an easier way to set up WAL archiving for backup.

You can use [PostgreSQL's continuous WAL archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/continuous-archiving.html) method. First you need to set `wal_level=archive`, then do a full filesystem-level backup (between issuing `pg_start_backup()` and `pg_stop_backup()` commands) and then just copy over newer WAL files by configuring the `archive_command` option.

Advantages:

- Incremental, the WAL archives include everything necessary to restore the current state of the database
- Almost no overhead, copying WAL files is cheap
- You can restore the database at *any* point in time (this feature is called PITR, or point-in-time recovery)

Disadvantages:

- More complicated to set up than pg_dump
- The full backup will be much larger than a pg_dump because all internal table structures and indexes are included
- Does not work well for write-heavy databases, since recovery will take a long time.

There are some tools such as [pitrtools](https://public.commandprompt.com/projects/pitrtools/wiki) and [omnipitr](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/06/02/omnipitr/) that can simplify setting up and restoring these configurations. But I haven't used them myself.

Comment: Just playing with this myself now and finding that even on windows (although most docs are linux heavy) this is not too bad without the tools

Comment: Since 9.1 there is pg_basebackup  - www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgbasebackup.html. It works with servers of the same or an older major version, down to 9.1. However, WAL streaming mode (-X stream) only works with server version 9.3 and later.

Answer (score 18):

Also check out http://www.pgbackrest.org

pgBackrest is another backup tool for PostgreSQL which you should be evaluating as it supports:

- parallel backup (tested to scale almost linearly up to 32 cores but can probably go much farther..)
- compressed-at-rest backups
- incremental and differential (compressed!) backups
- streaming compression (data is compressed only once at the source and then transferred across the network and stored)
- parallel, delta restore (ability to update an older copy to the latest)
- Fully supports tablespaces
- Backup rotation and archive expiration
- Ability to resume backups which failed for some reason
- etc, etc..

Comment: how to backup from standby ? I have /etc/pgbackrest.conf saying that backup-standby=y ,archive-async=y and remotebacup ini config tag in which contain db-port=5433 and db-host=lanip(192.168.0.3). In every times invoking /opt/perlroot/bin/perl /opt/perlroot/bin/pgbackrest --stanza=remotebackup stanza-create got error 124 remote process terminated on 192.168.0.3 exit status 255 : Permission denied public key . But strangely invoking from standby sudo -u postgres ssh 192.168.0.3 works fine. Adding cmd-ssh=/usr/bin/sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/ssh -vv didn't work either :(

Comment: Backing up from standby is covered in the pgbackrest documentation and mainly just involves setting up the replicas in the pgbackrest.conf file.  As for your permission denied issue, I can't really speak to it but you likely have a misconfiguration on your system regarding the SSH keys.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to backup to plain text and use rdiff to create incremental diffs.

Comment: Can't imagine doing that for a 5G database, let alone 50G ones.

Comment: I've used it on far bigger dbs than 50G in the past using snapshots of the data dir itself.  But yeah, once a plain test backup starts getting big and unwieldy it's a good idea to used some other method.

Comment: I don't know how barman works exactly, but WAL archiving does not save indexes as far as I know (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/continuous-archiving.html#CONTINUOUS-ARCHIVING-CAVEATS).

Comment: @ScottMarlowe, for what it's worth, have you tried a binary diff on the custom dump output format?

Comment: Surely rsync is better. Diff backups are not required here, just the ability to backup only what has changed.. ala rsync.

Comment: @Bladt WAL archiving does not save HASH indexes.  The default index type is a B-Tree.  Hash indexes are a special type.

Comment: @Doug Nice catch!

Comment: FYI: As of PG10, hash indices are wal-logged